# How to get all elements that can display text on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I want to write a script to replace all text meeting a condition with something else.
However, I don't want it to replace text in elements such as script, style, etc. which are not shown/rendered.
What is the best way to distinguish these elements?

```
//Example of idea:
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var element;
var text;

for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
  element = elements[i];
  //Need to detect only text that is displayed.
  text = element.textContent;
  if(checkText(text)){element.textContent = somethingElse;}//Abstract idea
}
```

Comment: what type of conditions you are expecting to match. Can u give some little detail?

Comment: @ajaiJothi The conditions are not completely decided, but are like "is word of this category". The problem is I want to use the script on any page without causing issues with tags like script, style, and I am not sure how many more like that there are(meta, old legacy tags). To get the text I am checking .textContent but this includes javascript inside script tags unfortunately. Ideally, there would be some property like .isRendered to distinguish from other .textContent that is used for meta, scripting, styling, etc. If anyone knows how other people are handling this, that would be OK too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
$(':contains("targetText")').text("newText");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the purpose of [`TreeWalker`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) and the [`document.createTreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) method:

```js
function getTextNodes (root) {

  var tw = document.createTreeWalker(root || document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, {
    acceptNode: function(node) {
      return /^(STYLE|SCRIPT)$/.test(node.parentElement.tagName) ||
             /^\s*$/.test(node.data) ? NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT : NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
    }
  })

  var result = []
  while (tw.nextNode()) result.push(tw.currentNode)
  return result
}

var textNodes = getTextNodes()

// Text nodes before
console.log(
  textNodes.map(function (n) { return n.data })
)

// Example text data transformation
textNodes.forEach(function (n) {
  n.data = n.data.toUpperCase()
})

// Text nodes after
console.log(
  textNodes.map(function (n) { return n.data })
)
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dot dolor sit amet...</p>
<span>More example text!</span>
<style>
  .omitted style { }
</style>
<script>
  'omitted script'
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery's star selector (`*`) and say `:not(script)` to the tags you want to ignore.

The following will replace any element that has the content "Test" with "Replaced", while ignoring any `<script>` and `<style>` tags.

```js
$("body *:not(script):not(style)").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "Test") {
        $(this).text("Replaced");
    }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Hello</li>
        <li>World</li>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```